# how to write XOM document to XML file with pretty print?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xom

I used the following code to write the xml

```
    import nu.xom.Document;
    import nu.xom.Element;
    import nu.xom.Serializer;

    Element root = new Element("ADT");
    root.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi","http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    root.setNamespaceURI("urn:hl7-org:v3");

    Element msh = new Element("MSH", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
    Element msh_1 = new Element("MSH.1", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
    msh_1.appendChild(m.getFieldSeperator());
    Element msh_2 = new Element("MSH.2", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
    msh_2.appendChild(m.getEncodingCharacters());

    msh.appendChild(msh_1);
    msh.appendChild(msh_2);

    root.appendChild(msh);
    Document document = new Document(root);
    Serializer serializer;
    serializer = new Serializer(System.out, "UTF-8");
    serializer.setIndent(4);
    serializer.write(document);
```

That prints my xml document on the console with pretty print. If anyone can help me to get the same same to an xml file? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream ("out.xml")
serializer = new Serializer(fileOutputStream, "UTF-8");
serializer.setIndent(4);
serializer.write(document);
//close fileOutputStream  ...
```